# How many routes in Rails before performance is affected? What key changes did you make to a scaffold/default generated Routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, routes

We are on Rails 2.3.

What is the upper bound on the number of routes Routes.rb can contain before performance is affected?

What are the key changes you made to the default Routes file created by scaffolding?

We like the default scaffolding in development since we can easily access/modify objects from the web as opposed to the database. However, this configuration is not tenable for a production environment. Is there a way to "activate" certain routes while in development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I always do is if you are doing resources, I always limit the routes by doing something like:

```
 map.resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy, :index]
```

You can just put the following in your routes.rb file

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  #production routes

else
  #development routes

end
```

Comment: Why would you use different routes in development compared to ant of the other environments? Recipe for debugging hell.

Comment: @Douglas only because we want to limit the number of exposed routes in production, but for development, we like using the default routes for hassle free, dead simple administration.  I suppose if we found the right admin gem we wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: I have no idea. I appreciate that Crashalot.